# Hibernate custom type mapping set length of char

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently implementing a custom type mapping in hibernate (Mapping UUIDs to char in order to set an index in oracle). I implemented the hibernate type `UUIDType` and `UUIDJavaDescriptor` and added them to our baseEntity (`JPAEntity`) via `@TypeDef`. The issue is that the columns are being generated as `varchar(255)` instead of `varchar(36)`. Annotating UUID fields via `@Column(length = 36, /* ... */)` works as expected but I don't want to annotate all UUID fields within the project. Does anybody know a way to adapt the length of all UUID fields globally?

```java
public class UUIDType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<UUID> {
  public static final UUIDType INSTANCE = new UUIDType();
  public static final String NAME = "uuid";
  public static final Size SIZE = new Size(0, 0, 36, Size.LobMultiplier.NONE);
  // define the column size                      ^^^

  public UUIDType() {
    super(VarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, UUIDJavaDescriptor.INSTANCE);
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return NAME;
  }

  // Override size related methods
  @Override
  protected Size getDictatedSize() {
    return SIZE;
  }

  @Override
  public Size[] dictatedSizes(Mapping mapping) throws MappingException {
    return new Size[] { SIZE };
  }

  @Override
  public Size[] defaultSizes(Mapping mapping) throws MappingException {
    return new Size[] { SIZE };
  }
}
```

```java
public class UUIDJavaDescriptor extends AbstractTypeDescriptor<UUID> {
  public static final UUIDJavaDescriptor INSTANCE = new UUIDJavaDescriptor();

  public UUIDJavaDescriptor() {
    super(UUID.class, ImmutableMutabilityPlan.INSTANCE);
  }

  @Override
  public UUID fromString(String string) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(string)) return null;
    return UUID.fromString(string);
  }

  @Override
  public <X> X unwrap(UUID value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
      return (X) toString(value);
    }

    throw unknownUnwrap(type);
  }

  @Override
  public <X> UUID wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    if (String.class.isInstance(value)) {
      return UUID.fromString((String) value);
    }

    throw unknownWrap(value.getClass());
  }
}
```

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@MappedSuperclass
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@TypeDefs({
  @TypeDef(typeClass = UUIDType.class, defaultForType = UUID.class, name = UUIDType.NAME)
})
public abstract class JPAEntity {
 // ...
}
```

Technical Details:

- Apache Maven 3.6.3
- openjdk 11.0.2
- Hibernate-Core 5.4.30.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change that, as the value 255 comes from the `javax.persistence.Column` annotation. Hibernate 6.0 will handle this properly, but for now, you'd simply have to set the length everywhere.